# Why In This Reaction Acetic Acid is strong acid and NH3 is strong base ?please explain in details and thanks for answer

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]
the acetic acid and amonia reaction why the reaction is towards completion and why nh3 and ch3cooh are strong

Answer (score 2):

"Weak" and "strong" are relative terms.  In the example shown in the question, ammonium ion is stronger than the acid on the other side of the equation, which is just water.  So it looks like a strong acid.  But if you rendered the following reaction instead things appear different:

$\ce{H_3O^+}+\ce{NH_3}\leftrightharpoons\ce{H_2O}+\ce{NH_4^+}$

Now the ammonium ion is compared with a hydronium ion, which is a much stronger acid than either plain water or ammonium ion.  Suddenly ammonium ion looks like only a weak acid.

We really should be using **comparative** terms.  In the reaction between ammonia and plain water **ammonium ion is a stronger acid than water.**  But in the reaction between ammonia and a mineral acid, **ammonium ion is a weaker acid than the hydronium ion.**